# SHA256 / SHA512: MySQL Code for Password Hashing and Salting

Tags: mysql, sql, hash, salt, sha256

I need some help understanding how to hash and salt passwords for users in SQL using SHA256 or SHA512. I think for each user I have to generate a different salt? How do I check the password at login and update and existing password in MySQL?

I used this resource to do some research on implementation but it only shows Java code, how do I do this in MySQL? Would this be done in a stored procedure?

Thanks

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no authority on the security aspects but using SQL Server you could handle the different pieces in the following manner:

> For Hashing:

You could use **`[HASHBYTES]`** and either of the SHA-2 algorithms based on your requirement. `HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', @Password);`
Be aware that this function takes only 8000 bytes and works on varchar, nvarchar, or varbinary, which should suffice in your case but just in case.

You could also write a **`SQL CLR`** function in .NET to do the hashing if the input constraints dont work for you.

> For the Salt:

Use **`GUIDs`** , using a part of the GUID might not give you the entropy required for a salt, so I recommend using the whole string.

or Use the **`RANDOM()`** function to generate a unique alphanumeric string with bit of logic.

> Process:

Add the `Salt` to the `Password` before hashing `(HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', @Password + Salt);`and store both the `Hashed output` and `Salt` for the user during the registration process.

On a subsequent login attempt, Add the `user-entered password with the salt` and get Hashed output and then compare it with the store hashed value. If the value matches then the user is legitimate else not.

Comment: Thank you, just a couple questions, could you show in more detail how to create and store the salt? Also would I store the hashed output of the HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', @Password + Salt) operation and the salt? So to authenticate a user I would take the generate salt and rehash with his entered password to match the stored Hash I have?

Lastly, would this be done in a stored procedure if it were to be done in SQL code or is it normally done in Java code using JDBC?

Comment: You would create a table to store the Hashed outputs and the Salt for every user (userid). For storing this generated data, you will have to look into SQL `Insert` and `Update` constructs. Your understanding for the authentication process is correct and yes all of this can be done in a SQL Procedure quite optimally.